# Add a App Bar to table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to react js and I have some problem with add some component to my table. For some experienced person it should be very easy.

This is my table - it's from Material UI:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        overflowX: 'auto',
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 700,
    },
});


let id = 0;

function createData(name, lastName, location, email, status, role) {
    id += 1;
    return {id, name, lastName, location, email, status, role};
}

const data = [
    createData("Jan", "Mucha", "Kraków ", "first@mail", "remote", "admin"),
    createData("Ewa", "Mucha", "Kraków ", "first@mail", "remote", "admin"),
    createData("Maciej", "Mucha", "Kraków ", "first@mail", "remote", "admin"),
    createData("Ula", "Mucha", "Kraków ", "first@mail", "remote", "admin"),
    createData("Iza", "Mucha", "Kraków ", "first@mail", "remote", "admin"),
];

function NextPersonTable(props) {
    const {classes} = props;

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <Table className={classes.table}>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell className={classes.head}>ID:</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className={classes.head} numeric>Name:</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className={classes.head} numeric>Last Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className={classes.head} numeric>Location</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className={classes.head} numeric>Email</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className={classes.head} numeric>Status</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className={classes.head} numeric>Role</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {data.map(n => {
                        return (
                            <TableRow key={n.id}>
                                <TableCell className={classes.innerRow} component="th" scope="row">
                                    {n.id}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell className={classes.innerRow} numeric>{n.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className={classes.innerRow} numeric>{n.lastName}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className={classes.innerRow} numeric>{n.location}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className={classes.innerRow} numeric>{n.email}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className={classes.innerRow} numeric>{n.status}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className={classes.innerRow} numeric>{n.role}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        );
                    })}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    );
}

NextPersonTable.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NextPersonTable);
```

And I want to add App bar with buttons to my table and I have a problem. Should I add this bar in the same class where my table is, or should I create new class jsx with this bar and should add like a component to this code? Please can someone help me?

Comment: That is up to you, any way you described can make sense. But as you named your component `NextPersonTable` it means it is just a table. If you follow Material convention, there is also a `Table` component and it does not contain an App Bar.

Comment: but when i add button code from Material - ui: https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/ it doesn't work

Comment: so then you have a complete different problem than you described here. So: Change your question where everybody can see, what your problem is and what you tried. Show us an example how you implemented the AppBar

Comment: i don't know how to implement:/ that's a problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I think you want to add something like:

```
function NextPerson(props) {
  render() {
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar />
        <NextPersonTable classes={this.props.classes} />
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

...
export default withStyles(styles)(NextPerson);
```

`NextPerson` is then the "full component" that wraps the table. (You might want to remove the `Paper` component from the table as well. You can also define `MyAppBar` the same way to customize the `AppBar`.

FYI, If you end up with other more 'props', you can just pass the whole thing onto `NextPersonTable` with `<NextPersonTable {...this.props} />`.

You could also continue to wrap `NextPersonTable` `withStyles` directly (and then not pass classes through) (in which case, you'd do something like `const StyledNextPersonTable = withStyles(styles)(NextPersonTable)` and then used the 'styled' table in the root component), or you could create a style constant for both, however you like.

Comment: So my question is there is possibility to add toolbar to this table?

Comment: Sure, you could put it anywhere. Semantically, a table is generally understood to be data, so putting control elements in the table is a little inelegant perhaps. But certainly possible. Just add a row, in the header makes sense but wherever you want works, and have the containing cell span all your columns (I assume you want the AppBar full width) and then add the AppBarbcomponent there.